# Elastic IP is gone after cancelling AMI image creation

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-ip

I created an AMI image, but cancelled it after 30 minutes of waiting. After that, my elastic IP which was assigned to the original instance is gone. It's not even in the `Elastic IPs` page.

How do I fix this, and is it possible to get the IP back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once an Elastic IP is released it cannot be re-assigned.